# Rubyで変数の中身をファイルに書き出したい

Tags: ruby

Rubyで一時的に変数の中身をファイルに書き出す良い方法を教えてください。
扱うのはハッシュか配列で、今まではJSONで書き出して、必要な時にパースして読み込んでいたのですが、容量が大きくなるに連れてパースにとんでもない時間がかかるようになりました。

JSONよりももっと低レベルの扱いで高速に書き出して読み込む方法はありますか?

Comment: http://tamata78.hatenablog.com/entry/2015/11/14/214114
使ったことがないですが、上記(Marshal)だと遅かったり問題があったりしますか？

Comment: データの内容と量は具体的にどの程度なのでしょうか。

Answer (score 1):

[MessagePack](http://msgpack.org) を使って、オブジェクトごとシリアライズ・デシリアイズしてみてはいかがでしょうか？ 使い方は [GitHub](https://github.com/msgpack/msgpack-ruby#serializing-objects) にありますが、基本的には（事前に `gem install msgpack` して）以下のような感じです：

```
require 'msgpack'
obj = 'Hello'
packed = obj.to_msgpack # さらにファイルに書き出すなど
unpacked = MessagePack.unpack(packed)
```

Answer (score 1):

PStoreなんかどうでしょうか。

```
require 'pstore'
db = PStore.new("/tmp/foo")
db.transaction do
  p db.roots       # => []
  ary = db["root"] = [1,2,3,4]
  ary[0] = [1,1.5]
end

db.transaction do
  p db["root"]     # => [[1, 1.5], 2, 3, 4]
end
```

https://docs.ruby-lang.org/ja/latest/class/PStore.html